# Stop Powerpoint from changing proofing language to keyboard language

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I use Powerpoint 2010 on Windows 7. My keyboard layout is German, but I write my presentations in English.

Now I created a presentation with Default Language set to English, and I want it to use English for proofing. When I create a new slide/textbox/... the language is indeed English. However **as soon as I start typing, the language changes** to German. This happens because my system-wide keyboard layout is set to German. If keyboard layout is changed to English, everything is alright.

Now I want to stop Powerpoint from changing its proofing language to match my keyboard language. I tried changing the `LangTuneUp` key  to Off or Prohibited in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\LanguageResources`as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/396110/how-to-prevent-system-locale-sniffing-in-ms-office-and-other-apps), but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

P.S. Oh how I *hate* it when application-developers try to be clever.

Comment: I'm grateful for this question, as I did not realize, that the problems I had with the proofing language in PowerPoint were driven by the keyboard language. Knowing that, I can switch my keyboard to English, when I work with PowerPoint and use this as a cumbersome workaround.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To disable Powerpoint from matching the system language (which fixes this very annoying behavior), go to **Options->Language**, then under **Choose Display and Help Languages** move "Match Microsoft Windows" and "Match Display Language" to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Any update for Windows 10 + PowerPoint 2016? What if the new default for Display and Help Languages is the same as the Windows Language?

Comment: This solution does not seem to work for me. I had it pretty low already and moving it to the end (and restating the application) did not resolve the problem.

Comment: This answer is not correct! Changing **display** language has nothing to do with the **proofing** language. PowerPoint is matching slide's language (proofing language) with your current keyboard layout and that is what you must change. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1727279/156554) below.

Comment: Here's an equivalent answer with helpful screen shots https://superuser.com/questions/1381821/how-do-you-change-word-2016s-display-language

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use your German keyboard layout while writing in English, you can create a new ”language” which uses the German layout but with English proofreading.

1. In the windows settings, got to **Time & Language → Language**.
2. Below **Preferred Language**, click on **Add a preferred language**.
3. Choose the language you want for the proofreading (i.e. English).
4. On the next page, unselect all checkboxes.
   (At least in my case, there were no checkbox for the proofreading, so the proofreading functionality will stay even if all checkboxes are disabled).
5. On the next page, choose your keyboard layout (i.e. German).
6. Follow the remaining steps of the assistent to create the new “language”.

Afterwards, you will have a new entry at the right of your taskbar where you can choose the German keyboard layout with English proofreading. You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch between the “languages”.

Comment: This solution works! In my case, I wanted to use my Hungarian keyboard for both English and Hungarian presentations. After setting the Hungarian keyboard for the English language, switching the proofing language did not switch to the English keyboard anymore -- it remained Hungarian. Thanks!

Comment: This has been driving me insane. I work for an English speaking company, but I'm Dutch. I switched Windows and Office to Dutch a while ago and I could not get PowerPoint to automatically detect the writing language like Word does. Setting the proofing language does nothing either. This did work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found [the given answer](https://superuser.com/a/1146820/156554) to be incorrect. In my case to solve this problem I had to change current keyboard layout to the language that I want to use in PowerPoint.

This could be achieve temporarily, by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> that many times until selected keyboard layout matches your desired proofing language:

[image]

After that PowerPoint will auto-match proofing language to your selected keyboard layout.

You may try to force-set this permanently, by changing selection *Use language list (recommended)* to your desired language in *Time & language → Typing → Advanced keyboard settings*:

[image]

But I found this not permanent / not working at all and must use first solution each time I use PowerPoint.

Source: [Prevent PowerPoint from auto-changing typing language](https://onezeronull.com/2022/04/23/prevent-powerpoint-from-auto-changing-typing-language/).