# Change Office 2016 language?

Tags: microsoft-office, language

I would like to change the default language for Office but I only have two choices:

1. Same as Microsoft Windows (which is in English)
2. Français

I would like to switch to English for all my office suite, but this option appear nowhere. What should I do?

I have Microsoft Office 2016 MSO and I have already tried to install the Language Pack `setuplanguagepack.x64.en-us_.exe`, but I got this error:

[image]

You can see here that I have no options to set my interface in english:

[image]

Comment: You want to change the language for editing, or displaying or both?

Comment: Only the inteface language

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you need to install language pack from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Then you should be able to change it.

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error when I attempt to install the Language Packs.

Comment: What error is shown when installing?

Comment: I was able to install French as another display language. Ensure that you select the correct version (just in case, Office version and 32 or 64-bit) before downloading the language pack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change Word 2016's Display language?](https://superuser.com/questions/1381821/how-do-you-change-word-2016s-display-language)

Comment: If you get an error you must provide an English translation otherwise we cannot help solve your problem

Comment: @Ramhound I added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: The official recommendation from Microsoft on error code 30029-1011 is to reinstall Office.  Have you tried that?  There is an [uninstall tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/error-code-30029-1011-when-installing-office-889d0ca8-1418-43f7-959e-334752b4a756) offered by Microsoft to make the process easy.

Answer (score 1):

[Language Accessory Packs for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f) are for Click-to-Run version of Office. If your Office 2016 is MSI installation, you can't use Language Accessory Packs to install languages for your Office. To installing languages for a volume licensed version of Office 2016, you can [download an ISO image of the language packs, language interface packs, and proofing tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/DeployOffice/office2016/customize-language-setup-and-settings-for-office-2016#DownloadLIPandProofTools) from the Volume Licensing Service Center (VLSC).

Comment: But we need an account to download it.