# Powerpoint 365 spelling language changes automatically

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, language, spell-check

In PowerPoint's *Language Preferences* I have English(United States) (installed and default) and Portuguese (not installed). During my editing of slides the language is constantly wanting to change to Finnish (I live in Finland and the computer is Finnish originally). I set the contents of a text box to be English, but as I make a new line (press Enter) it changes to Finnish.

**Why is Finnish a spell-checking option if it doesn't show in the *Language Preferences*? And why does it change on its own on new lines? Or in any context?** This a very undeterministic behavior. It's very hard for the user to keep track of incorrect changes. Is there a way to turn off this feature and use a single spell-checking language for the whole document?

Note: I have 3 keyboards set in Windows 10, FIN, POR and ENG. I don't really need the ENG one, so maybe I'll disable it. In any case keyboard layout shouldn't affect the spell-checker of a text editing software.

For now I'm changing the language on every new-line.

Comment: In PowerPoint, go to Review tab, in the Language group, click Language, Set Proofing Language, select English, click Set as Default.Yes to confirm and OK to apply it.

Comment: English is already default! Finnish doesn't even show as an option there.

Comment: Go to the Control Panel > Programs and Feature, select Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus - en-us, click Change > Online Repair to have a try.

Comment: When you start PowerPoint and create a new presentation, are the placeholder prompts in English or Finnish?  That is, the "Click here to ... whatever" things that appear where your title, text and other content will be.

Comment: @Steve It shows in English, for example "Click to add title".

Comment: @WinniL So this isn't a normal behavior? When looking at the program list I have several 365 ProPlus for many different languages.

Comment: @A.Vieira I don't have a Finnish system, so can't test this directly, but can you post a small sample file somewhere for me to look at? I may be able to sort out what's going on here. A link to dropbox/onedrive/etc would be fine. By the way, please mention exactly which version of Office you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Powerpoint from changing proofing language to keyboard language](https://superuser.com/questions/1010676/stop-powerpoint-from-changing-proofing-language-to-keyboard-language)

Answer (score 2):

I found out the problem for me.

You need to set your Keyboard to the Windows language, like so:

[image]

Then make sure you are using the right Language-Keyboard combination:

[image]

Comment: I've been looking to solve this issue for years, thanks you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also I've been looking for the answer for a very long time and only now I have found it !! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Powerpoint 2010 and found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1010676/stop-powerpoint-from-changing-proofing-language-to-keyboard-language): Under Options->Language, there is a list "Choose Display and Help Languages" in which "Match Microsoft Windows" and "Match Display Language" should be moved to the bottom. After restarting Powerpoint, the proofing language didn't change automatically anymore. Maybe this also works for Powerpoint 365.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Just a heads up for when you build a little more rep -- when you find that an answer on another question solves the problem, there's a good chance that the questions are duplicates.  We try to link the duplicates to make all of the solutions more accessible and avoid repeating answers.  Once you have a little more rep, you can flag a question to identify that.