# How to stop PowerPoint from being "smart" and constantly changing proofing language?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, language

I know this may sound like a duplicate of [Stop PowerPoint from changing proofing language to keyboard language](https://superuser.com/questions/1010676/stop-powerpoint-from-changing-proofing-language-to-keyboard-language) but the solution there doesn't seem to work.
I have Windows 10 20H2, build 9042.867 and PowerPoint v.2103.
My system language is English, and I have Russian installed as well.
My presentation is in Russian, but when I try changing the proofing language to Russian, it changes back to English within like a second. I have moved the auto detection to the bottom of the Spellcheck list in options, and Russian to the top. It doesn't help. I have tried changing keyboard layout, but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you change proofing language it affects only current paragraph.
You need to change global/template language.

Global:
`File >Options >Language` then select your desired language (Russian) as default.
(It's availible from `Revision>Language>[The second from drop-down]` too)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this! It is *not* a PP problem, it depends on the input language keyboard.
You are using the English keyboard in Windows 10 and that is why it keeps "smart" changing it to English. But you can change the keyboard of your preferred language.

1. Click on keyboard language on the bottom right part of the screen (ENG)
2. Language preferences
3. Under **Preferred languages** click **Russian** and then options
4. Add keyboard -> English (I guess your physical keyboard is
   English)
5. Delete the Russian keyboard from the Russian language
6. Now go back and move Russian as TOP preferred language

**Now you are writing in Russian but the keyboard is English! So PowerPoint won't change it when you set it to be default Russian in PowerPoint!**

Comment: This **definitely is** PowerPoint problem. It's their developers' decision to auto-match proofing language to your keyboard layout (a feature not found in other Office components). BTW: You can acheive your solution much faster by pressing `Win`+`Space` until you set your keyboard language to desired one (Russian in your case). Or you can [override default input method in your system](https://onezeronull.com/2022/04/23/prevent-powerpoint-from-auto-changing-typing-language/#change-keyboard-layout8230-forever). See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1727280/156554) below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File- Options- Language- make sure 2 options are all set to Russian language:
[image]

Comment: This answer is not correct (changing **display** language has nothing to do with the **proofing** language) and in my case inaccurate (changing authoring language in second list is correct, but in my case didn't solve the problem). PowerPoint is matching slide's language (proofing language) with your current keyboard layout and that is what you must change. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1727280/156554) below.

Answer (score 0):

I found [both](https://superuser.com/a/1690499/156554) [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1643715/156554) here to be incorrect or not enough. In my case to solve this problem I had to change current keyboard layout to the language that I want to use in PowerPoint.

This could be achieve temporarily, by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> that many times until selected keyboard layout matches your desired proofing language:

[image]

After that PowerPoint will auto-match proofing language to your selected keyboard layout.

You may try to force-set this permanently, by changing selection *Use language list (recommended)* to your desired language in *Time & language → Typing → Advanced keyboard settings*:

[image]

But I found this not permanent / not working at all and must use first solution each time I use PowerPoint.

Source: [Prevent PowerPoint from auto-changing typing language](https://onezeronull.com/2022/04/23/prevent-powerpoint-from-auto-changing-typing-language/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a permanent answer here, please upvote it if it works for you, it took me a very long time to find it:
https://superuser.com/a/1652362/1130787